# Add more tables to the existing dataset

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

How can I add more tables to an existing dataset? I have created a Data Factory to copy table data for 3 tables (Azure SQL Database).

Now I want to add two more tables to this. How do I do this?

Comment: I for one have not idea at all what you are asking. I would encourage you to expand your question to clarify the situation.

Comment: I have created a copy data activity in azure data factory to copy the tables from one azure sql database to another azure sql database. Now I want to add more tables in it and am not able to..

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameters to have only one dataset pointing to a database, and make it represent different tables, depending on the execution context.

Cathrine Wilhelmsen does a really good job explaining parameters in her blog: https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2019/12/20/parameters-azure-data-factory/

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to create 2 new datasets for your 2 new tables. Then add Copy Activity (2) in your pipeline referencing output dataset as your newly created dataset.

Comment: So there is no option to add more tables to the existing dataset ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue?

Comment: I have created a copy data activity in azure data factory to copy the tables from one azure sql database to another azure sql database. Now I want to add more tables in it and am not able to

Answer (score 0):

When you the copy data active executed, you can edit the pipeline to add the tables in dataset as the pipeline parameter.

For example, I copy two tables(`test` and `test4`) between two SQL database with COPY DATA.

When the pipeline execute successfully, editor the pipeline we can find that all the table name/schema mapping are set as parameter:
[image]

```
[
{"source":{"table":"test"},
"destination":{"table":"test"},
"copyActivity":{"translator":{"type":"TabularTranslator","mappings":[{"source": 
{"name":"id","type":"Int32"},"sink":{"name":"id","type":"Double"}},{"source": 
{"name":"tt","type":"String"},"sink":{"name":"name","type":"String"}}]}}},

{"source":{"table":"test4"},
"destination":{"table":"test4"},
"copyActivity":{"translator":{"type":"TabularTranslator","mappings":[{"source": 
{"name":"id","type":"Int32"},"sink":{"name":"id","type":"Int32"}},{"source": 
{"name":"tt","type":"DateTime"},"sink":{"name":"tt","type":"DateTime"}}]}}}

]
```

If you want add more tables, just editor the parameter json and  add a source json like bellow:

```
{"source":{"table":"test4"},
        "destination":{"table":"test4"},
        "copyActivity":{"translator":{"type":"TabularTranslator","mappings":[{"source": 
        {"name":"id","type":"Int32"},"sink":{"name":"id","type":"Int32"}},{"source": 
        {"name":"tt","type":"DateTime"},"sink":{"name":"tt","type":"DateTime"}}]}}}
```

So the new parameter should be:

````
  [
    {"source":{"table":"test"},
    "destination":{"table":"test"},
    "copyActivity":{"translator":{"type":"TabularTranslator","mappings":[{"source": 
    {"name":"id","type":"Int32"},"sink":{"name":"id","type":"Double"}},{"source": 
    {"name":"tt","type":"String"},"sink":{"name":"name","type":"String"}}]}}},

    {"source":{"table":"test4"},
    "destination":{"table":"test4"},
    "copyActivity":{"translator":{"type":"TabularTranslator","mappings":[{"source": 
    {"name":"id","type":"Int32"},"sink":{"name":"id","type":"Int32"}},{"source": 
    {"name":"tt","type":"DateTime"},"sink":{"name":"tt","type":"DateTime"}}]}}}

    {"source":{"table":"test6"},
    "destination":{"table":"test6"},
    "copyActivity":{"translator":{"type":"TabularTranslator","mappings":[{"source": 
    {"name":"id","type":"Int32"},"sink":{"name":"id","type":"Int32"}},{"source": 
    {"name":"tt","type":"DateTime"},"sink":{"name":"tt","type":"DateTime"}}]}}}

    {"source":{"table":"test7"},
    "destination":{"table":"test7"},
    "copyActivity":{"translator":{"type":"TabularTranslator","mappings":[{"source": 
    {"name":"id","type":"Int32"},"sink":{"name":"id","type":"Int32"}},{"source": 
    {"name":"tt","type":"DateTime"},"sink":{"name":"tt","type":"DateTime"}}]}}}

    ```

]
````

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried same by editing parameters..no validation errors..published and ran..but it failed with error (Operation on target ForEach_hhz failed: Activity failed because an inner activity failed)..all other tables copied data except the last newly added table.

Comment: @surya411 how many tables did you add? please check if all the added table failed or just the last table failed.

Comment: I have added only one table and I confirm all the tables are copied except the last newly added table.@Leon Yue

Answer (score -1):

You can only have 1 table for 1 dataset. Hence you have to create more datasets for more tables.

Comment: Also, what if I add another column in destination but not in Source table ? How can I map this ?